# PHP Merge Array during ForEach

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I am taking information from a JSON feed, and creating a JSON feed that I can use more easily across more devices.  The problem I am having is when creating the new array in PHP for the JSON feed, I need to use a `foreach` loop.  Here is my code for the foreach loop:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
$json_decode = objectToArray($obj);

$special_number = '0';
$special_number2 = '0';
foreach($json_decode AS $r) {
$info = explode('.', $json_decode[$special_number]['Id']);
$newarray = array( $special_number => array( 'client' => $info['4'], 'placementID' => $info['2'], 'creativeID' => $info['3'], 'dimensions' => $info['3'], 'impressions' => $json_decode[$special_number]['Impressions'], 'bxd' => $json_decode[$special_number]['BXD'], 'viewable_impressions' => $json_decode[$special_number]['ViewableImpressions'], 'exposure' => $json_decode[$special_number]['Exposure'], 'viewability_rate' => $json_decode[$special_number]['ViewableRate'], 'clicks' => $json_decode[$special_number]['AdClicks'], 'mouse_overs' => $json_decode[$special_number]['AdMouseOvers'] ));

$fullarray = array_merge($newarray);

$special_number++;
}
```

I am basically taking their arrays, reordering the info and getting only the data I need, and creating a new array with it, called `$fullarray`.  Each of the sub arrays I am making are generated each time, is it due to me running a `foreach` it is destorying the old `$fullarray`, and creating a new one?  It is giving me the following:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [client] => 
        [placementID] => 3
        [creativeID] => 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        [dimensions] => 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        [impressions] => 1
        [bxd] => 0
        [viewable_impressions] => 0
        [exposure] => 0
        [viewability_rate] => 0
        [clicks] => 1
        [mouse_overs] => 1
    )

)
```

I have searched for this, but I can not find it, other threads are about combining different keys and values, I am having to create subarrays to keep the keys the same, and have different values (this is what I want, yes.)

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Don't use `$json_decode[$special_number]['Id']` inside your foreach. Remember "foreach($json_decode as $r)" !! Use `$r['id']` inside. create new variables to work with `$json_decode[$special_number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$fullarray = array()
foreach(...) 
{
    ...
    $fullarray = array_merge($fullarray,$newarray);
}
```

The merge function can take more arrays parameters to be merged, in your case you did not merged the contents of fullarray to the new array, instead you overwrite it.

You may also need to declare full array before foreach